# ¿Cómo sumar elementos de un arreglo bidimensional dentro de un objeto con una estructura de bucle?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, function

Tenemos una tabla con el nombre; `tablaSalarios`, en cada elemento del array hay un `objeto` con dos propiedades: el nombre del empleado y el salario que ha obtenido anualmente durante 12 años.

En este ejercicio busco crear un nuevo array con la suma total que ha obtenido cada empleado durante los 12 años utilizando `estructuras de bucles` pero evitando emplear el método `reduce` o cualquier otro. De tal manera que la nueva tabla aparecería de este modo:
**[552330, 684470, 470510, 580094]**

*Código que he intentado:*

```
let tablaSalarios = [
  {empleado:"Rebeca",
salario:[12000,27130,68270,58050,30580,36790,40940,75810,58670,69010,51160,23920]},
  {empleado:"Laura",
salario:[67470,54850,74310,26670,24310,39000,72220,76010,51090,65560,62110,70870]},
  {empleado:"Manuel",
salario:[28310,26450,22420,50586,30124,70396,50556,30268,30186,60632,50319,20263]},
  {empleado:"Francisco",
salario:[40758,60212,70835,60240,65013,60639,40246,30244,50914,30338,20415,50240]},
];


function sumaTotal(objeto){
 
 let total = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < objeto.length; i++){
  total.push(0);
   for (let j = 0; j < objeto[i].length; j++) {
     total[i] += objeto[i][j].fact;
    }
 }
    return total
}

console.log(sumaTotal(tablaSalarios))
```

*Quisiera **evitar** la suma de los elementos con **metodo reduce**:*

```
function sumaTotal(objeto){
 
  let total = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < objeto.length; i++){
  let suma = objeto[i].salario.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
  total.push(suma)
    }
    return total
}

console.log(sumaTotal(tablaSalarios))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta respuesta es muy similar a la de masterguru, pero si no quieres molestar con índices lo puedes hacer así y (para mi gusto) queda mas limpio el código.

```js
let tablaSalarios = [{
    empleado: "Rebeca",
    salario: [12000, 27130, 68270, 58050, 30580, 36790, 40940, 75810, 58670, 69010, 51160, 23920]
  },
  {
    empleado: "Laura",
    salario: [67470, 54850, 74310, 26670, 24310, 39000, 72220, 76010, 51090, 65560, 62110, 70870]
  },
  {
    empleado: "Manuel",
    salario: [28310, 26450, 22420, 50586, 30124, 70396, 50556, 30268, 30186, 60632, 50319, 20263]
  },
  {
    empleado: "Francisco",
    salario: [40758, 60212, 70835, 60240, 65013, 60639, 40246, 30244, 50914, 30338, 20415, 50240]
  },
];

function sumaTotal(objeto) {
  let total = [];
  for (let empleado of objeto) {
    subtotal = 0;
    for (let salario of empleado.salario) {
      subtotal += parseInt(salario)
    }
    total.push(subtotal)
  }
  return total
}

console.log(sumaTotal(tablaSalarios))
```

Comment: Gracias @Pipe , yo también creo que así queda mucho más limpio, en vez de utilizar un for clásico y un reduce. Muchas gracias.